# How to replace binary package with catkin package?

Tags: ros, catkin, package, binaries

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'd like to reinstall the same package with catkin. The package is already installed using sudo apt-get install.

Can someone tell me how can I replace the existing package with catkin.

I'm using ROS Hydro, and the package that I'd to replace is rosserial.

Thanks in advance.

regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220690/how-to-replace-binary-package-with-catkin-package-?/) by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2015-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-11-10**:
Do you really want to install that system-wide for all users or do you just want to overlay the catkin package, so this is used in your workspace instead of the apt-get system package.

**Comment by [assil](https://answers.ros.org/users/10216/assil/) on 2015-11-10**:
I want to remove the old version of rosserial and install newer one using catkin ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can give catkin_make an install prefix in the usual cmake way, i.e., `catkin_make -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/opt/ros/hydro`.

Note that this will be overwritten as soon as you use a system install via apt-get.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0